# Weak convergence of independent random variable

Tags: probability-theory, weak-convergence, probability-limit-theorems

Let $(X_n)_n$ be a sequence of independent random variable such that $f_{X_n}(x)=\frac{1}{\Gamma(\alpha_n)}\lambda_n^{\alpha_n}x^{\alpha_n-1}e^{-\lambda_nx}1_{]0,+\infty[}(x).$
Let $U_n=\sum_{k=1}^nX_k.$

Prove that $(U_n)_n$ converges in distribution if and only if $\sum_{n}\alpha_n\ln(1+\dfrac{1}{\lambda_n})<+\infty.$

Supposing that $(U_n)_n$ converges in distribution to $U$, this means that $E[e^{-U_n}]=\prod_{k=1}^n E[e^{-X_k}]=\prod_{k=1}^n(\frac{\lambda_k}{\lambda_k+1})^{\alpha_k}$ converges to $E[e^{-U}]>0$ so
$\sum_n\alpha_n \ln(1+\frac{1}{\lambda_n})<+\infty.$

For the converse, I don't know if this attempt is true: $\sum_n\alpha_n \ln(1+\frac{1}{\lambda_n})<+\infty,$ which means $E[e^{-U_n}]$ converges to a limit $l>0$ so $P(\sum_nX_n<+\infty)>0$ so $P(\sum_n X_n<+\infty)=1$ since this event is tail event. We conclude since a.s converges implies convergence in distribution.

Comment: Please refer to https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3644895/. For $(U_n)_n$ converges in distribution, if and only if $\sum_n\alpha_n\ln(1+\frac1{\lambda_n})<\infty$.

Comment: you mean to use Levy theorem, the conditions are different. Is it possible that the condition $\sum_n\alpha_n\ln(1+\frac{1}{\lambda_n})$ is not necessary and sufficient?

Comment: To prove that $(U_n)_n$ converges in distribution $\implies$ $\sum_n\alpha_n\ln(1+\frac1{\lambda_n})<+\infty$,
your deduction "For the converse...." is also correct.